# Can't connect to a postfix server though port 25 is open

Tags: centos, postfix, email-server

I'm trying to connect via outlook to a postfix server (send example message via smtp).
On the server it seems the port is open:

```
 nmap -sT -O localhost

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-09-24 15:23 EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000046s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost.localdomain
Not shown: 990 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
21/tcp    open  ftp
22/tcp    open  ssh
25/tcp    open  smtp
80/tcp    open  http
110/tcp   open  pop3
143/tcp   open  imap
993/tcp   open  imaps
995/tcp   open  pop3s
3306/tcp  open  mysql
10000/tcp open  snet-sensor-mgmt
No exact OS matches for host (If you know what OS is running on it, see http://nmap.org/submit/ ).


Network Distance: 0 hops

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 12.06 seconds
```

but when I try to connect to the server via Outlook it seems it doesn't respond at all.
Here is a telnet check I've made(hostname9727.com is defined in my host file):

```
C:\Users\A>telnet hostname9727.com 25
Connecting To hostname9727.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 25: Connect failed
```

While with other ports like 110:

```
+OK Dovecot ready.
```

A connection is created

postconf -n

postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases home_mailbox = /home/virtual/mail/
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = /home/virtual/mail/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = hostname9727.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/24
myorigin = $myhostname
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

postconf -M

```
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
pickup     unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
```

Comment: From where are you connecting? Where is the server? Have you checked your firewall?

Comment: I'm connecting from my desktop.the server is located in the internet. I was able to connect to gmail's: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP 193sm2549783wmo.14 - gsmtp

The firewall doesn't block my connection.

Comment: port 25 is missing , when I scan with:  nmap -sT -O hostname9727.com
How can I fix it?

Comment: @Prognoza does sound like a firewall. You could have iptables? Or your provider?

Comment: iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

**my provider doesn't block ports on my server.**

Comment: Yes, but maybe your ISP blocks ports at home. You also don't seem to have submission (port 587) active, this means you won't be able to send mail from most residential ISPs. And you aren't supposed to send mail from email clients on port 25 anyway.

Comment: If my ISP were blocking my server's port 25, shouldn't gmail's be blocked too?

Comment: Then maybe your server provider actually does block ports on your server. You didn't [use the real hostname](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632), so nobody could check this.

Comment: currently no real DNS is forwarding towards this server. its ip is:31.220.108.9

Comment: @prognoza Try testing with `nc` (netcat). On your server try `nc -l 1234` then from home or wherever, do this `nc 31.220.108.9 1234`. When it connects, type messages back and forth to see that they're being received. Try other ports. Stop postfix and try `nc` with port 25 this time. See what happens. If other ports work, but not SMTP ports, something must be blocked. If nc works on port 25, then something is wrong with Postfix.

Comment: @prognoza You can also check to make sure Postfix is listening on the appropriate IP/port: `sudo netstat -antlp` The process will be called `master`.

Comment: @prognoza You can also try a `tcptraceroute` for port 25

Comment: after using nc -l 1234, I was able to telnet this port. nc 31.220.108.9 1234 failed:nc 31.220.108.9 1234
Ncat: Connection refused.
 nc -l 25
Ncat: bind to :::25: Address already in use. QUITTING.
sudo netstat -antlp
sudo: netstat: command not found
and how do I use tcptraceroute ?

Answer (score 6):

Your `postfix` server is configured to be reachable on the loopback interface only, as witnessed by the `postconf` output line:

```
inet_interfaces = localhost
```

If you want it to be reachable from other hosts you need to change that configuration by entering:

```
sudo postconf -e "inet_interfaces = all"
```

Comment: I did those changes, yet, I'm not table to connect to the relevant port.
nmap -sT -O hostname9727.com

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-09-25 23:39 EDT
Nmap scan report for hostname9727.com (31.220.108.9)
Host is up (0.000059s latency).
Not shown: 990 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
21/tcp    open  ftp
22/tcp    open  ssh
80/tcp    open  http
110/tcp   open  pop3
143/tcp   open  imap
993/tcp   open  imaps
995/tcp   open  pop3s
3306/tcp  open  mysql
10000/tcp open  snet-sensor-mgmt
33354/tcp open  unknown

Thanks!

Comment: `nmap` isn't the optimal tool for diagnosing this. First check your config again to see whether it now says `inet_interfaces = all`. Also make sure to restart the postfix service after changing the config. Then check which address the postfix master process actually listens on with `netstat -antp`, and check whether you can connect to port 25 on the external address from the server itself with `telnet 31.220.108.9 25`.